# SQL query to return the table structure

Tags: sql, properties

Knowing only the name of a table, is there a way in SQL to query the structure of the table so I can inspect the columns?

Comment: Which dbms? Check out INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

Answer (score 0):

This works in MS SQL server.This will show you column datatype and size.
`select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='<Table Name>'`